# Combine @Published property send values also when not updated

Tags: swift, combine

I was trying to create a dynamic Form using SwiftUI and Combine, that loads options of an input (in the example, `number`) based on another input (in the example, `myString`).

The problem is that the Combine stack get executed continuously, making lots of network requests (in the example, simulated by the delay), even if the value is never changed.

I think that the expected behavior is that `$myString` publishes values only when it changes.

```
class MyModel: ObservableObject {

    // My first choice on the form
    @Published var myString: String = "Jhon"

    // My choice that depends on myString
    @Published var number: Int?

    var updatedImagesPublisher: AnyPublisher<Int, Never> {
        return $myString
            .removeDuplicates()
            .print()
            .flatMap { newImageType in
                return Future<Int, Never> { promise in

                    print("Executing...")

                    // Simulate network request
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
                        let newNumber = Int.random(in: 1...200)
                        return promise(.success(newNumber))
                    }
                }
        }
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var model: MyModel = MyModel()

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(model.number ?? -100)")
            .onReceive(model.updatedImagesPublisher) { newNumber in
                self.model.number = newNumber
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `updatedImagesPublisher` is a computed property. It means that you create a new instance every time you access it. What happens in your code. The `Text` object subscribes to `updatedImagesPublisher`, when it receives a new value, it updates the `number` property of the Model. `number` is `@Published` property, it means that `objectWillChange` method will be called every time you change it and the body will be recreated. New `Text` will subscribe to new `updatedImagesPublisher` (because it is computed property) and receive the value again. To avoid such behaviour just use lazy property instead of computed property.

```
lazy var updatedImagesPublisher: AnyPublisher<Int, Never> = {
    return $myString
        .removeDuplicates()
        .print()
        .flatMap { newImageType in
            return Future<Int, Never> { promise in

                print("Executing...")

                // Simulate network request
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
                    let newNumber = Int.random(in: 1...200)
                    return promise(.success(newNumber))
                }
            }
    }
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}()
```

Comment: Thanks, I was mixing samples from https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/721/ (that was using UIKit) with SwiftUI, getting this wrong behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I assume it is because you create new publisher for every view update, try the following instead. (Tested with Xcode 11.4)

```
class MyModel: ObservableObject {

    // My first choice on the form
    @Published var myString: String = "Jhon"

    // My choice that depends on myString
    @Published var number: Int?

    lazy var updatedImagesPublisher: AnyPublisher<Int, Never> = {
        return $myString
            .removeDuplicates()
            .print()
            .flatMap { newImageType in
                return Future<Int, Never> { promise in

                    print("Executing...")

                    // Simulate network request
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
                        let newNumber = Int.random(in: 1...200)
                        return promise(.success(newNumber))
                    }
                }
        }
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }()
}
```